# How to call functions, written in compiled languages, from within a custom PIP package

Tags: python, c, numpy, rust, pip

*My particular case involves calling some **Rust** code from within **Python** code intended for a custom **PIP package**, but I would be interested in hearing how a similar problem might be solved when trying to call a function written in C, C++, Java, etc.*

### My Case: Calling Rust

This is my current method for calling a Rust function within Python:

1. Create a new Cargo package with `cargo new`.
2. Make sure your Cargo.toml file includes a line that looks something like `crate-type = ["dylib"]`.
3. Write your function in src/lib.rs.
4. Compile. This should generate a .so file.
5. Using the ctypes package, import the Rust library, and thus the function, into your Python code by giving the path to that .so file.

The above method seems to work for me perfectly well, if the Python code I'm calling the Rust from is just a script. I am sceptical whether it would work, however, **within the context of a custom PIP package**. I could not just assume that all the machinery would be in place to compile .rs files on someone else's machine; and it seems like a very very unwise move to try calling, say, `sudo apt install cargo` from within a SetupTools install script! To the best of my knowledge, the binaries which the Rust compiler spits out are no more portable than the executable produced by running `gcc my_code.c`. (Very happy to be corrected on that point.) But perhaps these .so files are different? **Could an .so, compiled on my machine, be perfectly useable on someone else's device?** If so, that would solve this problem. If not, then it looks like I will have to rethink the way I am going to combine Python and Rust on future projects.

### An Existing Example: NumPy and C

I had a chat a year or so ago with a colleague who had recently finished a PhD in which he used Python as the glue and C++ for the heavy lifting. When I expressed surprise at that combination of a supremely forgiving language with a supremely unforgiving one, he explained that actually several well-known Python libraries involve call to C and C++. (This conversation sparked my interest in calling lower level languages from Python.)

Specific examples of such Python libraries are not all the easy to find, but I have found one: **NumPy**, which actually is perhaps the most famous Python package outside of the standard library. Browsing through the package's GitHub pages, I can indeed see several .c files.

How does NumPy import that C code into its Python? I have not attempted to disentangle it fully, but NumPy seems to employ an intricate framework defined in NumPy itself. NumPy does not seem to require, either at installation or at runtime, any of its .c files to be compiled - although it would not be entirely unreasonable to assume that the machine in question already had a C compiler.

### Summary

- Can my current method for importing Rust code into Python be adapted for a custom PIP package?
- Can the NumPy current method for importing C code into Python be adapted for a custom PIP package?

Comment: From https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/building.html Prerequisites: Much of NumPy is written in C and C++. You will need a C compiler that complies with the C99 standard, and a C++ compiler that complies with the C++17 standard

Comment: This is usually not installed as a library with is `ctypes`ed into, but as a CPython extension. Rust has [`pyo3`](https://docs.rs/pyo3) for that purpose (C++ has libraries for that as well).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman But all the guidance surrounding pyo3 points you to using maturin, which requires your code to exist **within a virtual environment**, to point that I'm not sure it's even possible to use pyo3 without maturin. That's not a viable solution when you're developing a custom PIP package - unless you know something I don't.

Comment: @TomHosker If you check the [docs](https://pyo3.rs/v0.19.2/building_and_distribution), `pyo3` will make you pip packages (not sure if they meet your definition of "custom". Does that mean special?). They can be either built into wheels or installed from source. The latter will indeed require that rust is installed. (But you're right, you wouldn't put `apt install cargo` into the install script. The installation is up to the user, and if it's missing, there'll be an error along the lines of "Cargo is not installed or is not on PATH. Check  https://rustup.rs/​")

Comment: You might be interested in looking at how [`polars`](https://pypi.org/project/polars/) works which is a python library with the heavy lifting done in Rust